# Using MigLayout, how can I make JPanel appear

Tags: java, jpanel, miglayout

I have this ridiculously simple code (actually directly copied from the miglayout white paper: http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html). I added the panel.setVisible(true) at the end. The problem is, with or without that last line, nothing shows up.

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

panel.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"),   "");
panel.add(new JTextField(""),          "wrap");
panel.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"), "");
panel.add(new JTextField(""),          "");
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: try doing this `panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);` and see if it shows any blue color. also try to enable debug in miglayout initialization. `new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]", "debug");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the panel to a JFrame:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });    
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("fillx", "[right]rel[grow,fill]", "[]10[]");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter size:"),   "");
        panel.add(new JTextField(""),          "wrap");
        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter weight:"), "");
        panel.add(new JTextField(""),          "");
        //panel.setVisible(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MigLayoutTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

JPanel is not a top level frame, but JFrame, JDialog, and JApplet are. See this tutorial on top level containers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html